# Variable button increment picked from an input:range in React 18

Tags: javascript, react.js

I'm a newbye in React. I created some simple Components to practice. For now, I'm using class Component (I want learn either class COmponent or function COmponent).
I would know if I projected properly my Components or if I could have a better setting:
My little application allow to increment a number of 1 by default, but I can change the increment picked from an `input[type="range"]`

Counter.js:

```
    import { Component } from "react";

export default class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0, increment: props.step || 1 };
    this.incrementCount = this.incrementCount.bind(this);
  }

  incrementCount() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + this.props.step });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Il contatore attualmente è {this.state.count}</p>
        <button onClick={this.incrementCount}>Incrementa</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

StepCounter.js:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./Counter.js";

export default class StepCounter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { step: 1 };
    this.changeStep = this.changeStep.bind(this);
  }

  changeStep(e) {
    const clickedEl = e.target;
    const choosedStep = Number(clickedEl.value);
    this.setState({ step: choosedStep });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input
          type="range"
          name=""
          id=""
          min={1}
          max={10}
          step={1}
          value={this.state.step}
          onChange={this.changeStep}
        />
        <Counter step={this.state.step} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

and App.js:

```
import { Component } from "react";
/* import Counter from "./Counter"; */
import StepCounter from "./StepCounter";

export default class App extends Component {
  /*   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  } */

  render() {
    return <StepCounter></StepCounter>;
  }
}
```

It works but, I repeat, I would know if I could improve the design.

Comment: One think I notice is that you don't properly use the `prevState` to create the new state: `setState((prevState) => ({stateName: prevState.stateName + 1 }))`

Comment: Realy? I think this isn't the case. You suggest to use an updater function to modify the state but in my case I have no need.

Comment: You could be right, I just read that it's always safer to use the `prevState` argument to make sure you use the latest state. You might not see any difference in your case.

Comment: @Kokodoko Yes it's safer if you don't know how it works under the belt. This is a good discussion about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828368/why-react-usestate-with-functional-update-form-is-needed/73115899#73115899  In my case is the same

Comment: Apart from that you might consider using arrow functions in the handlers. `onClick={(e) => this.incrementCount(e)}>` and `onChange={(e) => this.changeStep(e)}`The reason is that you can remove the `bind` statements. But this too has huge amounts of discussion about which is better :). And when you keep reading the end conclusion is to switch to hooks :/